# posting data ajax, php

Tags: php, jquery

I tried to make a comment box, in which every user can delete  their own comments.

Everything is good, less delete button. I can comment but when i click x button(delete btn), there is not posted data before success.

[image]

jquery-code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.buton-stergere').each(function(){

        var buton = this;
        $(buton).click(function(){
            stergere_com(buton.id);

        });

    }); 

});

function stergere_com(_id_comment){

    $.post("/site/ajax/stergere_com.php", {
        task: "stergere_com",
        Serverside: true,
        id_comment: _id_comment
    }
    ).success(function(data)
    {
        console.log("succes");
    });

}
```

php code

```
if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'stergere_com'){
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/directoaredef.php';

    echo "server side";
}
```

html btn

```
 <ul>
    <li id="<?php echo $comment->id_comment; ?>" class="buton-stergere">X</li>

 </ul>
```

Comment: where does `$_POST['task']` come from ?!

Comment: try `stergere_com($(button).prop('id'));` instead of `stergere_com(buton.id);`

Comment: it comes from jquery code    $.post("/site/ajax/stergere_com.php", {
        task: "stergere_com",
        Serverside: true,
        id_comment: _id_comment
    }

Comment: lolka_bolka i tried but show me the same output

Comment: try without the loop and just `.click`

Comment: What are you trying to do. Please describe your expected output.

Comment: my expected output: succes, but before that i wanted to see posted data(in console) before succes. now it doesn't matter. Thanks all for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $.each, just use the button class for click event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.buton-stergere').click(function(){
            stergere_com(this.id);
           //stergere_com($(this).prop('id')); //you can use this also
    });    
});


function stergere_com(_id_comment){

    $.post("/site/ajax/stergere_com.php", {
        task: "stergere_com",
        Serverside: true,
        id_comment: _id_comment
    }
    ).success(function(data)
    {
        console.log("succes");
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you but not helped me at all! :( The same output .:(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.buton-stergere').each(function(){

        var buton = $(this);
        buton.click(function(){
            stergere_com(buton.attr('id'));

        });

    }); 

});

function stergere_com(_id_comment){

    $.post("/site/ajax/stergere_com.php", {
        task: "stergere_com",
        Serverside: true,
        id_comment: _id_comment
    }
    ).success(function(data)
    {
        console.log("succes");
    });

}
```

and if you need var buton to be the Javascript this - instead of jQuery object $(this):

```
var buton = this;
```

use:

```
var buton = $(this)[0];
```

Comment: the same output.. it shows me how many time i click delete button , ex : (5)succes

Comment: But before succes i should have, in console(post data) id_comment 3 , task : "stergere_com"

Comment: change console.log("succes"); to console.log(data); it will output exactly what's your php echo

Comment: it echoed "server side", partial was good your ideea but...no desired output :( THANKS!!

Comment: what is the data you want to output?

Comment: i wanted to see something  like:+POST: http:///localhost/ before "succes" message, but in chrome was not possible

Comment: install a Chrome complement like [Firebug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firebug-lite-for-google-c/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench/related). If installed Firebug, press F12 and check console tab